# Translate iOs dialogs in React Native app

Tags: ios, react-native, modal-dialog, translation

I have a React Native app with a WebView that access to a web page with a file upload.
The problem is that in iOs when the file upload input is touched it shows a modal with 3 different options that are displayed in English.

[Modal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSPOF.png)

The options are Take Photo or Video, Photo Library, and the last one is "Explorar" this one is being displayed in Spanish I don't know why.

I have looking for these texts or for any option to translate that but I didn't find anything in react documentation nor google.

I need to display these options in the same language (in Spanish), App Store is rejecting my app because of that

Thanks.